# How to access same variable across multiple dataframes in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, indexing, tibble

I'm working on a new project where I'm have a list of tibbles/dataframes. Each dataframe is the weekly outcome of a program, and the dataframes have the same variables each week (e.g. date, time, participants, topic), but varying numbers of rows each week. I would like to be able to access all entries of one variable across all the dataframes without using a loop. For instance, right now, if I want all the names, I have:

```
all_emails<-Fall2021[[1]]$email
for (i in 2:length(Fall2021)) {
  all_emails<-c(all_signups,Fall2021[[i]]$email)
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this without a loop. I know I can access a single variable in a single data frame with:

```
Fall2021[[1]]$email
```

But is there something like this, that actually works:

```
Fall2021[[:]]$email
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst <- list(
df1 <- tibble(date = c(2000:2009), 
              time = c(1:10),
              participants = c(30:39),
              topic = c(10:19)),

df2 <- tibble(date = c(2000:2020), 
              time = c(1:21),
              participants = c(30:50),
              topic = c(10:30))


)

lst %>% map_dfr(~ .x %>% select(date))
```